# Is altitude and heading your discretion when you are cleared visual approach?

Tags: air-traffic-control, visual-approaches

If I'm north of KSAN heading east and the controller clears me for the visual approach for runway 27, can I descend and turn the plane at my discretion so that I  can get ready for landing?

Also, once a controller clears me for the visual approach and I accept it, am I responsible for my own terrain and obstruction clearance?

Comment: Are you flying VFR? If so, then yes...

Comment: Same if you're IFR in VFR conditions.

Comment: @RonBeyer If you're cleared visual approach, it implies that you're on an IFR flight plan as far as I know.

Comment: Sweetwater visual for 27: https://aeronav.faa.gov/d-tpp/1902/00373SWEETWATER_VIS27.PDF

Comment: only requirement I can remember for visual app is to stay above minimum radar alt. You are responsible for both trafffic and ground separation,  but atc still needs to have you on radar

Comment: @Radu094 that's absolutely false, visual approaches in non-radar environments are common.

Comment: @pericynthion hmm...well, that’s true. Let me check the docs and see where this radar ideea comes from...

Comment: @Radu094. Nope. ATC Remains responsible for separation during a visual approach, unless an aircraft has specifically been instructed to maintain visual separation to another.

Comment: well, if ATC maintains separation, then that would be a good reason to stay in radar contact, so I remembered something fuzzy....Now why can’t I find my docs on visual approaches? Hold on, I need to get home to my desktop. edit: also just remembered noise abatement proc (if any) must still be respected in visuals.

Answer (score 4):

Visual approach procedures are discussed in AIM 5-4-23. A visual approach is an IFR procedure and you must be on and stay on an IFR flight plan. It authorizes you to proceed visually clear of clouds to the airport. You may make whatever normal maneuvers necessary to safely conduct the approach and landing including descents and turns. Under most conditions, you are responsible for your own terrain clearance and separation. The exception is if you have the airport in sight but not the aircraft you're following. ATC can still clear you for the visual but will retain radar separation responsibility.

Note that a visual approach is different from a "Charted Visual Approach Procedure," which [KSAN happens to have](https://aeronav.faa.gov/d-tpp/1902/00373SWEETWATER_VIS27.PDF) for Runway 27. If cleared for the charted visual, then you must fly it as depicted.